# How to retrieve the value from registry?

Tags: c#, registry

I want to retrieve the value from registry. For example like: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Manufacturer's name\Application name\InstallInfo`

Under the 'InstallInfo' there are so many variables, like 
ProductVersion, WebsiteDescription, WebSiteDirectory, CustomerName, WebSitePort etc.

I want to retrieve some values of these variables. I tried the following code but it returns

> *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'*

```
        var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

        regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ABC Limited\ABC Application\InstallInfo");

        if (regKey == null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Registry value not found !");
        }
        else
        {
            string dirInfo = (string)regKey.GetValue("WebSiteDirectory");
            Console.Write("WebSiteDirectory: " + dirInfo);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Did you check where does it throw this exception?

Comment: Have you checked if the Key is null or not because i had the same problem one time!

Comment: Yes, It throws exception in dirInfo = (string)regKey.GetValue("WebSiteDirectory"); line. dirInfo returns null so NullReference exception occuring.

Comment: @Anudeep - That means there is no such registry key.  Can you post the actual code your using?

Comment: @Ramhound I just edited my code with the actual. It is similar to the previous one, here just I handle 'null' situation. and registry key is present actually. But unable to retrieve it.

Comment: @Anudeep - If you are getting a null exception then the key where you are looking for it does not exist. If it was a permission problem you would get a different exception. Do us a favor export the registry SOFTWARE\ABC Limited\ABC Application\ to a text file and post it for us.

Answer (score 5):

`OpenSubKey` [returns `null` when it fails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx). That's clearly what's happening here.

It's failing because you are looking under the wrong root key. You are looking under HKCU but the key is under HKLM.

So you need

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SOFTWARE\Manufacturer's name\Application name\InstallInfo");
```

You must always check the return value when you call `OpenSubKey`. If it is `null` then handle that error case.

```
if (regKey == null)
    // handle error, raise exception etc.
```

The other thing to watch out for is the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). If your process is a 32 bit process running on a 64 bit system, then you will see the 32 bit view of the registry. That means that your attempt to view `HKLM\Softare` is transparently redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: In Registry.LocalMachine I am also facing same problem

Comment: Read all the way to the bottom of my answer. It's quite simple. `OpenSubKey` returns `null` when the subkey does not exist. That's what is happening. The obvious error in your original code was that you were looking in the wrong root key. The more subtle error is that the registry redirector may be confusing you.

Comment: I update my code with null handling. But I can't find the solution till now. My machine is 64bit and application setup I run is too x64 version. Why RegistryKey will go for WoW6432Node?

Comment: @Anudeep - By default a 64-bit process will only look at the 64-bit registry. You have to be very specific if you want to read the 32-bit location.  David answer is really clear with regards to `WoW6432Node`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you convert `regKey.GetValue("WebSiteDirectory")` to string, You should check it if it is null or not,

```
if (regKey.GetValue("WebSiteDirectory")!=null)
 //do the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are looking under wrong root key.

It should be:

```
Registry.CurrentUser
```

instead of

```
Registry.LocalMachine
```

Here you go:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Manufacturer's name\Application name\InstallInfo");
```

Comment: In Registry.LocalMachine I am also facing same problem